# How to automatically create user accounts ( SSH + LDAP )

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, ldap, pam

I set up remote LDAP server (Server1) and SSH with pam_ldap on Server2. Everything is working ok, I can login to SSH with LDAP credentials. But when I want to add new user, I have to firstly create it in LDAP databases and then run adduser  on Server2.

How can I automatically create the user account on Server2 after adding it to LDAP database ? For example when the user first logs in? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to actually make the user on the server2, only their home directory on first login. You're looking for pam_mkhomedir:

http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_mkhomedir.html

Google will find you many howtos and examples on getting this set up.

Comment: the link is already dead :(

Comment: I've updated the URL. "already" is a linguistic stretch, this comment is 9 years old.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the LDAP module for NSS?

See here on how to do this: http://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/NSS

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a working procedure for Debian on [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM#Creating_home_directory_on_login)

Here it is:

Create `/usr/share/pam-configs/mkhomedir` file

Fill it with the following content:

```
Name: Create home directory during login
Default: yes
Priority: 900
Session-Type: Additional
Session:
        required        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
```

Run the following command as root (or sudo) to update PAM configuration:

```
pam-auth-update
```

Login with non-existing user should now create it on the target system